# Throughput for creation of nodes in Neo4J decreases significantly with the number of properties

Tags: neo4j

I am doing an A/B testing to measure the throughput for the Creation of nodes in Neo4J. And I find throughput for creation of nodes decreases significantly as the number of properties increase.

**Setup:** Neo4j cluster 3.5.7 (3 core instances where one is the leader and the rest two are followers)

**TestA:** Is to measure the throughput for creation of nodes in Neo4j  where each node has 20 properties.

**TestB:** Is to measure the throughput for creation of nodes in Neo4j cluster 3.5.7 where each node has 40 properties.

**Result:  Throughput for TestB = 1/2 * Throughput for TestA**

Below is the code I used to generate the load and measure the throughput.

```
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.*;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class UnwindCreateNodes {

    Driver driver;
    static int start;
    static int end;

    public UnwindCreateNodes(String uri, String user, String password) {
        Config config = Config.build()
                .withConnectionTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .toConfig();
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, AuthTokens.basic(user, password), config);
    }


    private void addNodes() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> listOfProperties = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int inner = start; inner < end; inner++) {
            Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
            properties.put("name", "Jhon " + inner);
            properties.put("last", "Alan" + inner);
            properties.put("id", 2 + inner);
            properties.put("key", "1234" + inner);
            properties.put("field5", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field6", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field7", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field8", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field9", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field10", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field11", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field12", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field13", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field14", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field15", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field16", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field17", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field18", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field19", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field20", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field21",  "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field22", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field23", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field24", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field25", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field26", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field27", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field28", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field29", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field30", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");

            properties.put("field31",  "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field32", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field33", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field34", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field35", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field36", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field37", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field38", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field39", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            properties.put("field40", "kfhc iahf uheguehuguaeghuszjxcb sd");
            listOfProperties.add(properties);
        }

        int noOfNodes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfProperties.size() / 5000; i++) {
            List<Map<String, Object>> events = new ArrayList<>();
            for (; noOfNodes < (i + 1) * (5000) && noOfNodes < listOfProperties.size(); noOfNodes++) {
                events.add(listOfProperties.get(noOfNodes));
            }
            Map<String, Object> apocParam = new HashMap<>();
            apocParam.put("events", events);
            String query = "UNWIND $events AS event CREATE (a:Label) SET a += event";
            Instant startTime = Instant.now();
            try (Session session = driver.session()) {
                session.writeTransaction((tx) -> tx.run(query, apocParam));
            }
            Instant finish = Instant.now();
            long timeElapsed = Duration.between(startTime, finish).toMillis();
            System.out.println("######################--timeElapsed NODES--############################");
            System.out.println("no of nodes per batch " + events.size());
            System.out.println(timeElapsed);
            System.out.println("############################--NODES--############################");
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        driver.close();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        start = 200001;
        end = 400001;
        if (args.length == 2) {
            start = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
            end = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
        }
        UnwindCreateNodes unwindCreateNodes = new UnwindCreateNodes("bolt+routing://x.x.x.x:7687", "neo4j", "neo4j");
        unwindCreateNodes.addNodes();
        unwindCreateNodes.close();
    }
}
```

Below is the graph.

[image]

It takes 3.5 seconds to insert 5000 nodes where each node has 40 properties

It takes 1.8 seconds to insert 5000 nodes where each node has 20 properties

This is a significant slowdown and 40 isn't a big number for the number of properties. I have a requirement until 100 properties but if I it does not scale for 40 I am not sure how I can scale for 100?

Other approaches I tried are using `apoc.periodic.iterate` With taking out `UNWIND`and without `UNWIND` just using `CREATE` etc but the behavior persists.

I don't want to store properties in some external store like RDBMS etc because that complicates things for me because I am building a generic application where I have no idea what properties are going to be used.

I cannot use CSV tool either because my data is coming from Kafka and also it is not structured in a way CSV tool wants. so no CSV tool for me.

Any idea to speed this up?